# Declaring WinJS.xhr globally in win 8 metro app

Tags: javascript, html, winjs

I am working on windows 8 metro app. I have an issue i have a hub page where i have pushed data from an XML API dynamically. I have used two WinJs.xhr(" url" ) one url to push the headings and one url to push datas into section. Now the issue is when i merge both winjs and try to push to the items the second winjs items gets pushed not the first one. I have to declare first url globally as i have many pages.  SO where and how to declare it globally.>

Answer (score 0):

The global object in `WinJS` is still `window` so declare it this way:

```
window.url = url;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define a custom name space in default.js with this

```
WinJS.Namespace.define("MYAPP",
{
gvar:123,
myurl1:'http://example.com/url1',
myurl2:'http://example.com/url2'
}
);
```

Then, include first the js and set the xhr url like this:

```
WinJS.xhr({url:MYAPP.myurl1})....

....

WinJS.xhr({url:MYAPP.myurl2})....
```

Comment: Thank you for replying. I defined in default.js and am i supposed to include and set the js and xhr in same default.js or in the js page where am fetching the data? because when i included in hubPage.js its giving me an error which redirects to base.js saying the system cannot relocate the resource.